# How can I remove vim-plug, so I can migrate to Packer?

Tags: plugin-vim-plug, packer

I upgraded to neovim, and I want to remove [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). It randomly changes my style settings (literally turns on `syntax on` for no reason other than the author's preference), and it's not as nice as newer neovim plugin managers like [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) which are written in lua. I don't see what's pulling it in. How can I remove `vim-plug`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With vim, `vim-plug` is installed in

  ```
  ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim*
  ```
- With neovim `vim-plug` is installed in

  ```
  ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim*
  ```

Simply removing those file will stop it from loading. You'll furhter want to delete the place where the plugins are stored, `~/.config/nvim/plugged/`.

You can then proceed with installing [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim)